# How does update statements in package get executed?

Tags: ssis

In SSIS package,
If I have multiple Update statements in a step, how do they get executed sequentially or parallely?

-- Kinjal.

Comment: What is a "step" in your mind? Are you describing multiple OLEDB Commands transformations in a data flow or multiple Execute SQL Tasks in the control flow?

Comment: Why dont you put that query through SSMS to view the query execution plan. It should show you how SQL Server will execute the statement.